# Simpless not compiling automatically

Tags: less

My simpLESS stylesheets have stopped compiling automatically. If I open the actual simpLESS program and click the refresh icon it builds them without a problem.

But it's stopped listening to when I save them. Anyone know how to make simpLESS listen again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got in touch with the SimpLESS technical support guys at wearekiss.com, they said "I noticed that from time to time, too. When I remove the indexed LESS files from SimpLESS and restart the App, it seems to be working again."

I tried that, it failed, so I uninstalled and reinstalled SimpLESS, then reindexed files, now it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

Simpless will not warn you if you're missing a variable declaration... it just won't compile, which is really confusing since in will warn you for other errors. It appears as if Simpless just stopped working.

What you should do is paste your code here: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler to find what variables you aren't declaring, then fix it in the original LESS file, then SimpLESS will continue working fine.